# Error Compiling Beamer Presentation

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, pgfkeys, beamer-metropolis, everyshi

With due respect, my file having the following environment:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pdfsync}
\usepackage{placeins}
\newcommand{\dif}{\mathrm{d}}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=0.4cm}
\setbeamersize{text margin right=0.4cm}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newcommand{\x}{\mathbf{x}}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
```

**the error that shows is as follows:**

```
LaTeX Warning: You have requested package `everyshi',
               but the package provides `everyshi-2001-05-15'.
)))
(C:\Users\A\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfrcs.code.te
x (C:\Users\A\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\pgf.revision.tex)))
(C:\Users\A\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys.code.
tex
(C:\Users\A\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfkeys.code.t
ex
(C:\Users\A\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfkeysfiltere
d.code.tex))
! Undefined control sequence.
\pgfkeyssetevalue ...pandafter {\pgfkeys@expanded
                                                  {#2}}}
l.17 \pgfkeys{/pgf/.is family}
```

Comment: Please format your code. See [How do I format code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361)

Comment: *Under no circumstance should you be loading the `pdfsync` package.* The `subfigure` package has been deprecated for close to 20 years; don't use it!.  Why do you run `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`--  not once, but twice? Delete both instances immediately. Do not load the `epsfig` package. Do *not* use the `times` package with the `beamer` document class -- unless you're absolutely sure you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

Too long for the comment:

- Do you really need all those packages?
- Some packages in your preamble are load twice, some are obsolete (`subfigure`) , some are already loaded by `beamer` (`xcolor`, `amsmath`) ...
- check how old `beamer` you use (recent version is 3.64)

Try to cleanup your preamble. See, if the preamble from the following MWE (Minimal Working Example) is sufficient in your document:

```
\documentclass[utf8]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=0.4cm}
\setbeamersize{text margin right=0.4cm}
\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}  
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} % beter is to use utf8, it is loaded by beamer option
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%\usepackage{graphicx}  % loaded by beamer
%\usepackage{epsfig}    % not needed, obsolete
%\usepackage{subfigure} % obsolete use subfig instead (see next line
\usepackage{subfig}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}  % loaded by amssymb
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
%\usepackage{amsmath}   % loaded by beamer
\newcommand{\dif}{\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand{\x}{\mathbf{x}}
%\usepackage{pdfsync}   % not needed
%\usepackage{placeins}  % beamer hasn't floats, superfluous
%\usepackage{color}     % in conflict with xcolor loaded by beamer
\usepackage{longtable}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} % duplicate

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test}

Some dummy math 
    \begin{align}
a & = b   \\
  & = \int_0^1\x\dif\x,\qquad x\in\mathbb{R}
    \end{align}
    \begin{figure}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image-duck}}
\hfill
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image-duck}}
\caption{My lovely ducks}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Above MWE works fine (no warnings, no errors). Its preamble should work in your document to (well, its content is unknown).

[image]

**Edit:**

My MWE I tested (again) by recent version of MiKTeX (21.10) as well by Overleaf ([on-line service](https://www.overleaf.com) service). In the both cases the compilation went smooth: no errors, no warnings.

If above MWE (as it is) still make the mentioned errors, than probably faced by:

- (very) old LaTeX installation (try to upgrade it to its recent version), or
- you changed something in my MWE, or
- you test in your document and errors are caused by unknown part of your document.

I suggest you that you first test my MWE as it is and than on step-by-step way add other frames from your presentation until you discover where errors occurs.

Let repeat me again: compilation of proposed MWE doesn't throw any warnings or errors.

Comment: Thank you so much @Zarko. I just tried with your provided example but the same error appears. In addition, I was not aware about the obsolete and twice-loaded packages. Now as I got it, in future, I will try with your provided code.

Comment: @TahirUllahKhan, please provide MWE which reproduce your problem. In constructing of it, please start with the first your frame (put `end{document}` after it) and see, if errors occur. If it, than show us this part of document. You  may have an ancient LaTeX installation too. Try to upgrade it. So far you provide too little information about your document, so we cannot help you further.

Comment: @Ingmar, thank you for editing my answer!

Comment: Still having the same error which I have already mentioned above.

Comment: @TahirUllahKhan, upgrade your LaTeX installation

Comment: @TahirUllahKhan, se added explanation. It may help you.

Comment: thanks for your precious comments. You are right! Now I have come to the conclusion that I have an old version of Miktex, that is the Miktex 2.9. I tried to search   MiKTeX (21.10) online but did not find. Kindly guide how can I find it to install.

Comment: @TahirUllahKhan, you not need to reinstall MiKTeX from scratch, just upgrade it by use MikTeX Console. In it select "Updates" and then "Check for updates." After then will be listed new version of packages. They you can install by "Update now".  All instruction you can find on https://miktex.org/